# Create a true/false variable in R

Tags: r, string, stringr, dplyr

I have one variable column that contains large string values which are multiple words. I want to create a True/False column which reports true if a certain value is detected within the column of interest.

I have tried a mutate function with an embedded str_detect.

```
Dataset <- Dataset %>%
  mutate(new_column = str_detect('column.of.interest', "abcd"))
```

My expected output was for all rows in which my column of interest contained "abcd" would report as TRUE in my new column. However, every row reports as FALSE in my new column.

Comment: You shouldn't be quoting the column name: `str_detect(column.of.interest, "abcd")`

Comment: Should work fine without the quotes around `column.of.interest`, voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one answer which from based on a dataset from `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>% mutate(newCol = str_detect(clarity, "1"))
```

---

Original bad version of answer (see comments for why the above is better)

```
diamonds %>% mutate(newCol = ifelse(str_detect(clarity, "1"), "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Comment: This is bad. `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` with quotes are `character` class, not `logical` class. This can break things, e.g., `isTRUE("TRUE")` returns `FALSE`. To keep the answer from being bad, it should be `ifelse(str_detect(clarity, "1"), TRUE, FALSE)`. But even then the `ifelse` isn't needed. `str_detect` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you don't need to use `ifelse` to convert to `TRUE` and `FALSE`. The simpler `mutate(newCol = str_detect(clarity, "1"))` is better.

Comment: You don't even need the `mutate`. Do it directly: `diamonds$newCol = str_detect(diamonds$clarity, "1"))`

Comment: @Gregor, thank you, but you should not delete your comment.

Comment: Okay. Re-edited your question to lead with the better answer but still have context for the comment.

Comment: This solved my issue! The problem was I had ' ' around my column of interest. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Base R version. First create a sample data set (questioner: you should have done this; answerers: you should always do this):

```
> Dataset = data.frame(ID=1:10, column.of.interest=c(NA,"This","abcd","Foo","the abcde",NA,"Me","my","mo","END"))
```

which looks like this:

```
> Dataset
   ID column.of.interest
1   1               <NA>
2   2               This
3   3               abcd
4   4                Foo
5   5          the abcde
6   6               <NA>
7   7                 Me
8   8                 my
9   9                 mo
10 10                END
```

Then do:

```
> Dataset$new_column <- grepl("abcd", Dataset$column.of.interest, ignore.case = T)
```

to get:

```
> Dataset
   ID column.of.interest new_column
1   1               <NA>      FALSE
2   2               This      FALSE
3   3               abcd       TRUE
4   4                Foo      FALSE
5   5          the abcde       TRUE
6   6               <NA>      FALSE
7   7                 Me      FALSE
8   8                 my      FALSE
9   9                 mo      FALSE
10 10                END      FALSE
```

You may or may not want `ignore.case`.